# BesselI and BesselK with complex arguments

Tags: complex-numbers, special-functions

I would like to check with you the following issues.

During my work, I ended up with following Bessel Functions.

BesselI(0, i*x) and BesselK(0, i*x).   (Modified bessel functions of first and second kind.)

Usually I have come across with BesselJ(0, i*x) and BesselY(0, i*x). (which are the bessel functions of first and second kind with complex arguments).

Is it okay to have a BesselI and BesselK with complex arguments. Can we write them any way in real form.

Your time and inputs are greatly appreciate.

Regards

Comment: "Is it okay..." - Yes.

Answer (score 0):

That was asked and answered in [MaplePrimes](http://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/148361-BesselI-And-BesselK-With-Imaginary-Arguments).